# Subform updating another subform dates

Tags: vba, ms-access, iif

I have a form with two subforms, one holds a clients details, the other the client's bookings, and this form compiles client details and bookings to make an invoice.
Due to GDPR and my own sanity I am required to delete a clients details 4 years after their last booking, but they may have many invoices over a number of years.  At the moment every time i create an invoice it updates a control on the client details subform to the last booking in that invoice (as below), is there a way to make it check which date comes last and keep that one?  I've had a play with Iif but am just really struggling.

At the moment i have

```vb
Private Sub Booking_subform_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    [booking contact subform].[Form]![latest booking].Value = [booking subform].[Form]![Max DATE]
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly you want to find the last date of all invoices for a client, correct? Try to use DMAX function:

```vb
DMax ( expression, domain, [criteria] )
```

It is similar to DLookup but it returns the highest value.

Comment: Why do you want to do update a control? Just use Update query direct against data. Do it in AfterUpdate event.

Comment: I don't think that would work in this instance, the code I have just replaces the latest booking date, I need to essentially have the following to update the latest booking control when i exit the booking subform.`iif[booking contact subform].[Form]![latest booking]]<[Max Date],[max date],[latest booking]`, but can't make that work.  In all honesty, i'm really not that great with VBA, as i'm sure you can tell.

Comment: In all honesty, I'm getting pretty lost in the whole DB now, and because i didn't know there was another way?  the idea is this data sticks with the client as it is used in a few other situations.